# Android RelativeLayout won't scroll when in landscape mode

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout, landscape

I have a RelativeLayout in my app, but when the phone is in landscape mode it won't scroll. I read that I need to put it inside a ScrollView but I keep getting errors, so I might not be doing it right.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff8400"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_nomeSpot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/nome"
    android:inputType="text" 
    android:gravity="center" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_coordSpot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_nomeSpot"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/coordenadas"
    android:inputType="text" 
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_classSpot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_coordSpot"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/classif"
    android:inputType="text" 
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_tipoSpot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_classSpot"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/tipo"
    android:inputType="text" 
    android:ems="10" 
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_subtipoSpot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_tipoSpot"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/subtipo"
    android:inputType="text" 
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_moradaSpot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_subtipoSpot"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/morada"
    android:inputType="text" 
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_submitSpot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_moradaSpot"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/submeter" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply have the ScrollView as the top level element. Your existing RelativeLayout then goes inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff8400"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        ...other existing code here

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

EDIT: I've changed the height of your RelativeLayout to "wrap_content" since kabuko is correct in what he says in his answer.

Comment: I did just as you told me and it came out like this: http://s30.postimg.org/g3hw5hfjl/unnamed.png

What did I did wrong?

Comment: My mistake - try setting the RelativeLayout width back to "match_parent" but leave the height as "wrap_content".

Comment: Now it's like this: http://s23.postimg.org/tnfbo9rvv/Screenshot_2014_01_11_01_17_02.png

It's getting closer thow...

Comment: Try moving the android:background statement to the scrollview. Does it then look like your original version? If not, post that image too and perhaps ask kabuko for further advice under his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You do need a `ScrollView`, but it doesn't make sense for the `View` inside to be of height `match_parent`. That would make the inside `View` the same size as the `ScrollView` leaving nothing to scroll. You need to set the inner `View` (in this case your `RelativeLayout`) tall enough to show all of its content. Generally, that means `wrap_content`.